# Failed to reorder the commits via git rebase

Tags: git

I want to swap the blue box and red box

[image]

But I failed to do it with `git rebase 1e74133` then change the commits position

[image]

I got the error message,

It told me the problem was at 
`adavanced_collection`

But it didn't help to do  `git add adavanced_collection`

I don't know how to exchange the commit order in this case.

How to ? Thanks

```
% grbi 1e74133                                                                                                                               (git)-[master]
error: Updating the following directories would lose untracked files in it:
    04-adavanced_collection/python_hw

Aborting
Could not apply eff7b98ad02c49ab737a23fc5047a6b26da683b4... rename course 04


Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    04-adavanced_collection/
```

Original history

```
* 073f187 ignore useless files
* f64bbdd add course06 lecture
* 16dc565 add course06 resource
* eff7b98 rename course 04
* e7a1f28 hw5:list all not-fixed common bugs
* 42d6ede hw5: convert bugs into a list
* d48da21 hw5: clean the common bug text
* eb353e3 hw5_sol: read line and find the target line
* 404184c add solution for HW5 : common bugs
* 1e74133 update 2015-01-23 course info
```

Expected history after rebasing

```
* e7a1f28 hw5:list all not-fixed common bugs
* 42d6ede hw5: convert bugs into a list
* d48da21 hw5: clean the common bug text
* eb353e3 hw5_sol: read line and find the target line
* 404184c add solution for HW5 : common bugs

* 073f187 ignore useless files
* f64bbdd add course06 lecture
* 16dc565 add course06 resource
* eff7b98 rename course 04  

* 1e74133 update 2015-01-23 course info
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer here depends entirely upon what's actually in those commits. Your best course of action would probably be to ask a co-worker with more experience with git to look at your tree, and figure out why the rebase fails.

Some typical situations where these kinds of rebase failures happen would be, for example:

1) A commit removes a file, and you rebase that commit prior to an earlier commit that modifies a file, so the commit now tries to modify a file that has already been removed, during a rebase.

2) The flip opposite -- a commit adds a file, a later commit changes the file, and you move the later commit before the earlier commit.